# INNO setup error "Out of System Resources"

Tags: windows, installation, inno-setup

I have a script in Inno Setup  to generate an .EXE install program.
All worked fine, but from some time ago, when running the generated .EXE installation file a dialog box with "Out of system resources" error message appears; but the installation continues and works correctly!  Tested in several computers, always this same behaviour.
No change has been done on the Inno Setup script from before this error, the script compiles fine, and when debugged, no error appears! So the error seems to come from Windows?  The setup  program basically checks in the registry if the program is already installed, then it copies some files. As I said, this error started to appear maybe 2-3 months ago, when no changes have been done in the script.
Any idea of the origin of this error?

Screenshoot:
[image]

Beginning of the log file where the error appears "Out of system resources", (remaining is just the list of copied files to the target dir):

```
    2019-01-23 16:40:54.742   Log opened. (Time zone: UTC+01:00)
2019-01-23 16:40:54.742   Setup version: Inno Setup version 5.6.1 (a)
2019-01-23 16:40:54.742   Original Setup EXE: C:\Users\myuser\Downloads\Update__v5_5.exe
2019-01-23 16:40:54.742   Setup command line: /SL5="$1009EE,629487447,58368,C:\Users\myuser\Downloads\Update__v5_5.exe" /log="C:\Users\myuser\Downloads\install.log"
2019-01-23 16:40:54.742   Windows version: 10.0.17134  (NT platform: Yes)
2019-01-23 16:40:54.742   64-bit Windows: Yes
2019-01-23 16:40:54.742   Processor architecture: x64
2019-01-23 16:40:54.742   User privileges: Administrative
2019-01-23 16:40:54.784   64-bit install mode: Yes
2019-01-23 16:40:54.786   Created temporary directory: C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Temp\is-70UEO.tmp
2019-01-23 16:40:54.789   -- DLL function import --
2019-01-23 16:40:54.789   Function name: IsModuleLoaded2
2019-01-23 16:40:54.789   DLL name: files:psvince.dll
2019-01-23 16:40:54.789   Extracting temporary file: C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Temp\is-70UEO.tmp\psvince.dll
2019-01-23 16:40:54.809   Dest DLL name: C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Temp\is-70UEO.tmp\psvince.dll
2019-01-23 16:40:54.809   Importing the DLL function.
2019-01-23 16:40:54.810   Successfully imported the DLL function. Delay loaded? No
2019-01-23 16:40:54.835   Message box (Yes/No):
                          The current version seems to be already installed.
Please use "Check for updates" option in MyProgram applications 
to check if you need to install some update.

If you continue with this installation all the files will be overwritten
2019-01-23 16:40:55.780   User chose Yes.
2019-01-23 16:40:55.828   Exception message:
2019-01-23 16:40:55.828   Message box (OK):
                          Out of system resources.
2019-01-23 16:40:57.749   User chose OK.
2019-01-23 16:41:00.283   Starting the installation process.
2019-01-23 16:41:00.288   -- File entry --
2019-01-23 16:41:00.289   Dest filename: d:\MyProgram\psvince.dll
2019-01-23 16:41:00.290   Time stamp of our file: 2014-09-29 23:06:42.000
2019-01-23 16:41:00.290   Dest file exists.
2019-01-23 16:41:00.290   Time stamp of existing file: 2014-09-29 23:06:42.000
2019-01-23 16:41:00.290   Version of our file: 1.1.0.0
2019-01-23 16:41:00.291   Version of existing file: 1.1.0.0
2019-01-23 16:41:00.291   Same version. Skipping.
2019-01-23 16:41:00.292   -- File entry --
2019-01-23 16:41:00.292   Dest filename: d:\MyProgram\MyProgram.exe
2019-01-23 16:41:00.292   Time stamp of our file: 2016-10-11 12:55:28.000
2019-01-23 16:41:00.292   Dest file exists.
2019-01-23 16:41:00.292   Time stamp of existing file: 2016-10-11 12:55:28.000
2019-01-23 16:41:00.292   Installing the file.
2019-01-23 16:41:00.433   Successfully installed the file.
```

Comment: Show us a screenshot + Installer log file.

Comment: Done for screenshot! Accepting this error the install continues and works without problems. Tested in several PC's with same result. But there are no  Installer log file. As I said, when debugging the installer in Inno, it doesn't show any error. That's why I guess the error may directly come from Windows??

Comment: How come that there *"are no Installer log file"*? Did you use `/log` switch? + Is the dialog modal? (can you interact with the main windows, while the dialog is showing?)

Comment: Yes, the error dialog is modal. And sorry, we didn't used /log switch. Now we tested it and I added  the beginning of the  log file to my question.

Comment: At what point of the log, do you get the error message?

Comment: Do you get the problem with any Inno Setup installer? If not, we need [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

We finally started a new script from the scratch, adding one by one the lines from the script that was failing and testing it.
The result was unexpected: the error came from adding a background image!! As I said, this script, without any change, was running without problems for months. So we don't have an explanation for this sudden error.
But I hope this information can be useful for someone else.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem going from version 5.5.9 to version 5.6.1 of Inno Setup Compiler.

I thought the problem was loading the "WizardImageFile" image when setup was started.
To solve the problem I specified:

```
[Setup]
PrivilegesRequired=admin
```

Comment: The default setting for this option it should be "admin" http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_privilegesrequired ... maybe it's a inno setup v5.6.1 problem.